# Do I need to escape get_theme_mod('url') / ('mail') with esc_url?

Tags: escaping

Question is in the title, thanks in advance (:

Comment: it depends if you want to produce HTML, JSON or other format.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you do. Even if you have sanitised the value when saving it, you should always escape on output.

```
<a href="<?php echo esc_url( get_theme_mod( 'url' ) ); ?>">
```

If you're outputting a `mailto:` link to an email address, you also need to escape this with `esc_url()`, just make sure that the `mailto:` part is included in the escaped value, so that it's a valid URL:

```
<a href="<?php echo esc_url( 'mailto:' . get_theme_mod( 'mail' ) ); ?>">
```

Comment: Thank you. What kind of escape should I use (if any) when I use get_theme_mod to input text inside p or h1 tag for example? 
Eg: <p> <?php echo get_theme_mod( 'text' ); ?> </p>

Comment: Use `esc_html()`